# How to use @Keyframes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Hey I was wondering how To use @keyframes In Js.

Because I want to make the animation begin in css but at 90% I want it to happen in Javascript.

So the animation will continue and doesn't stop before the js animation begin

Example :

```
@keyframes spin {
    0 % {
        transform: rotate( 0deg);
    }
    50 % {
        transform: rotate( 1080deg);
    }
    100 % {
        // I want to make it happen in js , container.style.transform = "rotate(" + number + "deg)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work? `document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "rotate(7deg)";`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp

Comment: You would need to listen for `animationend` or `transitionend` event to know when the css has finsihed its animation/transition

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: I want an hybrid solution,  like the animation should begin in CSS and end in JS

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to animations, CSS and JavaScript have limited interactions with one another. If you really want a hybrid solution, it will require you to syncronize the timing between the CSS keyframes, and the moment JS starts animating in the last portion.

If you need to animate a 1080 deg spin, followed by a dynamic last position, I would set the rotation value in JS while setting a CSS transition for the DOM's rotation.

CSS

```
container{
  transition: transform 3s ease;
  transform: rotate( 0deg );
}
```

With this CSS any change to `.container`'s transform value will animate to the new value with a duration of 3 seconds on an ease curve. We also need to set an initial value, so the animation knows where to start from.

Next, you can then set the custom rotation value in JS with the added 1080 degrees.

```
container.style.transform = `rotate( ${number + 1080}deg )`;
```

Now the container element will spin for the duration set in the CSS transition, landing on the final position declared by `number`.

**Update**

Based on your comments, you could apply the following conditional logic.

```
const angle = number > 500 ? number + 1080 : number;
container.style.transform = `rotate( ${angle}deg )`;
```

If the smaller number makes the animation move more slowly, you can have JS apply a class that has it's transition sped up.

Comment: If I get It I must set the transition in css and the rotate in js ? But what if I don't have a number variable for the last example I just want to say If the number < 500 then the rotation of the container is set at container.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";  It can't be "rotate(0deg" + 1080deg)".

Comment: Then you add a conditional as to whether or not to include the 1080 in the styles.